# How to get grandchild in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, hierarchy

How to display children and grandchildren when 'parentItemNo' is given.

Below is my model: Any record (itemNo) can become a parent, child, or grandchild.

```
public partial class item
{      
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }         
    public string ParentItemNo { get; set; }     
}
```

Below query returns children: Would like to display grandchildren as well.

```
 var result = Context.Items.Where(p => p.ParentItemNo == parentItemNo).Select(p => p.ItemNo).ToListAsync(); ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation properties.

Given an Item class which can have multiple levels where each item can have an optional Parent:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public string ParentItemNo { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}
```

From here I would recommend setting up the mapping explicitly, either in the DbContext OnModelCreating event or using an EntityTypeConfiguration implementation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(x => x.Children);
```

When you want to get the children and grand-children for an item:

```
var children = await context.Items
    .Include(x => x.Children) // eager load children
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Children) // eager load grandchildren
    .Where(x => x.ItemNo == parentItemNo)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Normally though you'd load the parent with it's children and grandchildren eager loaded:

```
var parent = await context.Items
    .Include(x => x.Children)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Children)
    .SingleAsync(x => x.ItemNo == parentItemNo);
```

For eager loading you need to plan ahead with what data you expect to need, otherwise you should ensure lazy loading is enabled and available if it's possible that a grandchild could itself have children items. Iterating down to this level would either attempt a lazy load (possibly resulting in errors if the object is orphaned from it's DbContext) or return no data or a partial representation of data if the DbContext was already tracking some of the great grandchildren that it could fill in.

Edit: if you just want to get the Item Numbers of the children and grandchildren then you don't need to use the eager loading with `Include` as that would be to return entities and their related entities. Projection with `Select` / `SelectMany` does not need this.

To select the ItemNos of any Children and Grandchildren:

```
var childDetails = await context.Items
    .Where(x => x.ItemNo == parentItemNo)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children.Select(c => new 
    {
        c.itemNo,
        GrandChildItemNos = c.Children.Select(gc => gc.itemNo).ToList()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

What this will give you is a list of anonymous types containing each child's Item #, and the list of that child's grandchild item #s. From there you can combine all of the item #s:

```
List<string> itemNumbers = childDetails.Select(x => x.itemNo).ToList();
foreach(var child in childDetails)
    itemNumbers.AddRange(child.GrandChildItemNos);
```

This would combine all of the item numbers for the children and their grandchildren into a single list. From there if relationships to a particular child could be doubled up (2 children share the same grandchild) you can add a `Distinct()` to the end to remove duplicates.

It may be possible to select both child and grand child in the EF Linq operation using something like a Union but if possible I'd expect it to be a fair bit more complex and might be difficult to modify and understand later on.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I tried changing code as suggested (please refer above). But I get an error while returning data. May I know which return type should be used or if there is something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Your return type is `IEnumerable<string>`, so what do you want to return? If you want to return the children Item entities then the return type should be `Task<IEnumerable<Item>>`. If it's the Child itemNos or Names then change the `SelectMany` to `.SelectMany(x => x.Children.Select(c => c.itemNo))` or ` ... => c.name` respectively.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to return  ItemNos of children and grandchildren. Adding SelectMany(x => x.Children.Select(c => c.itemNo)) worked. But it returns only children, not grandchildren. Whereas lazy loading returns error (please refer above for the implemented  code). How do i return grandchildren as well.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to outline how you could retrieve the Item #'s for the children and their grandchildren.

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks a lot. Would like to know if there is any chance that I can get grandchildren using my existing model above (without using navigation properties)? because this table is used by another application as well. Would like to not touch the model if there is a way. Thanks.

Comment: Because existing model accepts empty strings for "ParentItemNo", I had to convert all empty strings to NULL to add navigation properties to the model. If not I was getting "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint" error

Comment: Looks like adding navigation property do not need migration and doesn't affect or change the existing table. That's amazing. I was doing Add-Migration and Update-Database earlier, my mistake.

Comment: I need to distinguish which children ‘ItemNo’ returned which grandchildren ‘ItemNos’. Instead of one list with all together. I tried eager loading query to check if that works as per my requirement but that returns only children ItemNos.

Comment: That is what you would have with the query before the last step that combined the children and grandchildren. To preserve the relationship you either need a data structure that represents the relationship or a data container that has the item number and optional parent item number. Eager loading only applies if you need the entire entities and their related entities returned, it isn't needed if you project out fields with `Select`.